# Event onclik button em tabela html dinâmica StringBuilder

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, webforms

Boa tarde pessoal do forum, estou tentando adicionar um button em uma tabela html dinâmica para redirecionar para outra pagina passando parâmetro pela url. Mas não estou conseguindo via javascript. Estou utilizando WebForms asp.net C#. Montei a seguinte função para escrever via StringBuilder o html da tabela na pagina aspx:

```
    public void LoadTable()
    {
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.Append("<table class = 'table table-hover'>");
        html.Append("<tr><th>Processo</th><th>Parte Contraria</th>"+
            "<th class='text-center'>Pesquisa/bens</th>"+
            "<th class='text-center'>Status</th><th class='text-center'></th></tr>");

        foreach (var item in ProcessoCRUD.GetProcessoRank())
        {                
            html.AppendFormat("<tr style='cursor: pointer;'><td>{0}</td>", item.ProcessoID);
            html.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", item.ParteContraria);

            if(item.PesquisaBens == false)
                html.AppendFormat("<td class='text-center'><i class = 'fa fa-thumbs-o-down' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Não pesquisou!'></i></td>", item.PesquisaBens);
            else
                html.AppendFormat("<td class='text-center'><i class = 'fa fa-thumbs-o-up' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Pesquisou!'></i></td>", item.PesquisaBens);

            if (item.Ativo == true)
                html.AppendFormat("<td class='text-center'><span class = 'label label-success'>Ativo</span></td>", item.Ativo);

            if(item.Arquivado == true)
                html.AppendFormat("<td class='text-center'><span class = 'label label-primary'>Arquivado</span></td>", item.Arquivado);

            if(item.Irrecuperavel == true)
            html.AppendFormat("<td class='text-center'><span class = 'label label-danger'>Irrecuperavel</span></td>", item.Irrecuperavel);

            html.AppendFormat("<td><button id='btnVisualizar' runat='server' class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='tooltip' "+
                "title='Visualizar' href='javascript: void(0)' onclick='window.open('Processo.aspx?NumeroProcesso={0}')>"+
                "<i class='fa fa-search'></i></button></td></tr>", item.NumeroProcesso);
        }
        html.Append("</table>");

        //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
    }
```

Não consigo redirecionar para a pagina Processo.aspx?NumeroProcesso={0}.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia explicar uma forma de escrever um button via StringBuilder para redirecionar para outra pagina.

Comment: Tente alterar onclick=""window.open('Processo.aspx?NumeroProcesso={0}') ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obrigado pessoal pela ajuda!
Resolvi de outra maneira sem usar javascript, no próprio html assim:

```
            html.AppendFormat(
                "<td>" +
                "<a href = \"Processo.aspx?NumeroProcesso={0}\"" +
                "class=\"btn btn-default\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\"" +
                "title=\"Visualizar\"><img src=\"#\"" +
                "class='fa fa-search'></a></td>" +
                "</tr>", item.NumeroProcesso);
```

Função completa:

```
    public void LoadTable()
    {
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

        html.Append("<table class = 'table table-hover'>");

        html.Append(
            "<tr><th>Processo</th><th>Parte Contraria</th>"+
            "<th class='text-center'>Pesquisa/bens</th>" +
            "<th class='text-center'>Status</th>" +
            "<th class='text-center'></th></tr>");

        foreach (var item in ProcessoCRUD.GetProcessoRank())
        {                
            html.AppendFormat("<tr style='cursor: pointer;'>" +
                "<td>{0}</td>", item.ProcessoID);

            html.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", item.ParteContraria);

            if(item.PesquisaBens == false)
                html.AppendFormat(
                    "<td class='text-center'>" +
                    "<i class = 'fa fa-thumbs-o-down' " +
                    "data-toggle='tooltip' title='Não pesquisou!'>" +
                    "</i></td>");
            else
                html.AppendFormat(
                    "<td class='text-center'>" +
                    "<i class = 'fa fa-thumbs-o-up' " +
                    "data-toggle='tooltip' title='Pesquisou!'>" +
                    "</i></td>");

            if (item.Ativo == true)
                html.AppendFormat(
                    "<td class='text-center'>" +
                    "<span class = 'label label-success'>" +
                    "Ativo</span></td>");

            if(item.Arquivado == true)
                html.AppendFormat(
                    "<td class='text-center'>" +
                    "<span class = 'label label-primary'>" +
                    "Arquivado</span></td>");

            if(item.Irrecuperavel == true)
            html.AppendFormat(
                "<td class='text-center'>" +
                "<span class = 'label label-danger'>" +
                "Irrecuperavel</span></td>");

            html.AppendFormat(
                "<td>" +
                "<a href = \"Processo.aspx?NumeroProcesso={0}\"" +
                "class=\"btn btn-default\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\"" +
                "title=\"Visualizar\"><img src=\"#\"" +
                "class='fa fa-search'></a></td>" +
                "</tr>", item.NumeroProcesso);

        }
        html.Append("</table>");

        //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Escrevi o exemplo de como escrever em C#, para aprendizado.

Começando a string com '@', é possível quebrar de linha e adicionar aspas com ""

```
    html.AppendFormat(
@"<td>
<button id='btnVisualizar' runat='server' class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Visualizar' href='javascript: void(0)' onclick=""window.open('Processo.aspx?NumeroProcesso={0}')"">
<i class='fa fa-search'></i>
</button>
</td>", item.NumeroProcesso);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa concatenar a string de forma que retorne um `HTML` válido.

Nesse ponto o `HTML` deixa de ser válido:

```
<td>
  <button id='btnVisualizar' 
      runat='server' 
      class='btn btn-default'     
      data-toggle='tooltip' 
      title='Visualizar' 
      href='javascript: void(0)'
      onclick='window.open('Processo.aspx?NumeroProcesso={0}')>
    <i class='fa fa-search'></i>
  </button>
</td>
</tr>
```

Você precisa que o `HTML` saia nesse formato:

```
<td>
  <button 
      id="btnVisualizar"
      runat="server" 
      class="btn btn-default"     
      data-toggle="tooltip"
      title="Visualizar" 
      href="javascript: void(0)"
      onclick="window.open('Processo.aspx?NumeroProcesso={0}');">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </button>
</td>
</tr>
```

Tente concatenar da seguinte forma:

```
    html.AppendFormat(
    "<td>
        <button 
           id=""btnVisualizar"" 
           runat=""server"" 
           class=""btn btn-default"" 
           data-toggle=""tooltip"" 
           "+"
           title=""Visualizar"" 
           href=""javascript: void(0)""
           onclick=""window.open('Processo.aspx?NumeroProcesso={0}');"">
           "+"
           <i class=""fa fa-search""></i>
        </button>
   </td></tr>", item.NumeroProcesso);
```

Obs.: A identação dos exemplos estão assim só para facilitar nossa visualização do código.

Comment: obrigado pela obs. da identação.